# How do I set the icon for a program I compiled manually with cl.exe?

Tags: c++, windows, cl

How do I set the icon for an executable when I'm creating the executable at the command prompt with `cl.exe`?

Comment: You do it with the linker, not the compiler.  Find useful hits by googling "c++ how to create a resource script".  Using an IDE so it just turns into point-and-click isn't exactly going to hurt either.

Comment: Yea, I have a habit of getting familiar with processes manually before using ides to automate them.  I find it leads to more success for me in the long run.  One less layer between me and the strange device while I'm figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate the compiling and linking stage for this to work.

Assuming your c file is called `main.c`, you already have an icon called `myicon.ico`, and you want to generate the executable `program.exe`:

1. Create a `.rc` file, for instance, `program.rc` with the following content:

```sh
IDI_ICON_1 ICON "myicon.ico"
```

The `IDI_ICON_1` is an arbitrary ID that you can use in your application via a `#define` statement. But just for the application icon, you don't need to do anything.

2. Compile your source file(s) to generate objects/lib (will create `main.obj`):

```sh
cl -c main.c
```

3. Generate the resource file (will create the file `program.res`):

```sh
rc program.rc
```

4. Link your objects with the resource file:

```sh
link main.obj program.res -out:program.exe
```

The program should now appear with the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Use resource hacker to edit icon of an .exe file